# How does myMethod method reference differs from myMethod[T] for scala compiler?

Tags: scala, scalaz

Consider the following lines of code:

```
def fixBr[U](v: U)(implicit l: Lens[U, String]): U = ???
def fixAsterisk[U](show: Boolean)(v: U)(implicit l: Lens[U, String]): U = ???
def fixLinks[U](v: U)(implicit l: Lens[U, String]): U = ???

def fix1[T](show: Boolean)(what: List[T])(implicit l: Lens[T, String]) =
  what ∘ fixAsterisk(show) ∘ fixBr[T] ∘ fixLinks[T]

def fix2[T](show: Boolean)(what: List[T])(implicit l: Lens[T, String]) =
  what ∘ fixAsterisk(show) ∘ fixBr ∘ fixLinks
```

(this funny unicode character ∘ is just a scalaz map)

Why is that that `fix1` is a valid Scala code and in `fix2` case compiler complains about missing implicit argument `l` to functions `fixBr` and `fixLinks`? It seems to me, that compiler **should** be able to see that U == T